# Azure web apps angular 5 + dotnet core 2.1 refresh after deployment

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application

I have a SPA project via angular 5 and dotnet core 2.1.

After I deployed it to Azure web apps, the user has to refresh the browser a couple of times to get the latest frontend changes.

I already included this in the header section of the HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

What do I have to do so that the users don't need to refresh the browser to get the latest changes after deployment?

(Does assembly version play a role in this? How do I manage dotnet core assembly version?)

Answer (score 0):

Try below too

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```